# Field.function / method not automatically updating field odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-10

I have a function which currently works when a user pick an item from a drop down menu and there is also other fields.

However the other field only changes when I click save how can I make this that as soon as I change the value of the drop down field, then other fields value also changes with having to click on save button?

Comment: Can you update your code ?

Comment: how to apply onchange on fields to update in same model on click savebutton                                                         @api.onchange('schedule',)
 def _onchange_schedule(self):
  for item in self:
   current=self.env['hr_work_shifts.hr_shifts'].search([('schedule','=',self.schedule)])
  print "::::::::::::::::::::"